# Sort vectors by last elements

Tags: c++, vector, sorting

Have a "vector of vectors"
that looks something like this

```
3 1 2 0 77
0 3 1 2 44
1 0 3 2 29
3 0 1 2 49
```

I would like to sort them according to the last element in every row so that it would look like this in the end

```
1 0 3 2 29 
0 3 1 2 44
3 0 1 2 49
3 1 2 0 77
```

Of course my real example is a lot more complex... but this is basically what I need to get done.
Right now I use this snippet which seems to sort according to the first elements.

```
vector<vector<int>>population;
partial_sort( population.begin(),population.begin()+10, population.end() );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with a function (or functor object) that provides a strict weak ordering for vectors.  I.e. you define a vector-less-than function that orders two vectors correctly, something like this (off the top of my head).
Edit: after comments, added checking for one or two empty vectors, which does make things trickier.

```
bool CustomVectorCompare(const std::vector<int> &i_lhs, const std::vector<int> &i_rhs)
  {
  if(i_rhs.empty())
    return false; // If right side is empty, left can only be equal or larger

  if(i_lhs.empty())
    return true;  // Consider an empty vector to be "smaller" 
                  // than any non-empty vector.       

  return i_lhs.back() < i_rhs.back();
  }

  std::sort(population.begin(), population.end(), CustomVectorCompare);
```

Comment: Thanks will try it out...
Thought I could just put a parameter or something to get it to compare the nth elements but...

Comment: Make sure you augment this code for the case where one of the vectors is emoty.

Comment: You can also use vector::back() instead of *vector::rbegin()

Comment: Dur... where's my head at this morning... Thanks for that RPG.

Comment: In the above reworking, that never happens.  It early-outs for either vector being empty.

Comment: A very good solution, IMO. Unfortunately, I've already up-voted it, so I can't up-vote again. `:)`

Comment: Shouldn't you overwrite operator() instead of operator< ?

Comment: @Code_So1dier - you are completely right, and what's more, the functor wasn't needed at all.  I've rewritten my answer to use a simple comparator function instead.

Answer (score 6):

Use a simple std::sort and pass a functor that compares only the vector's last elements.

> Partial_sort rearranges the elements in the range [first, last) so that they are partially in ascending order. Specifically, it places the smallest middle - first elements, sorted in ascending order, into the range [first, middle). The remaining last - middle elements are placed, in an unspecified order, into the range [middle, last).

Comment: thanks..
Well I want to partially sort in my example to save cpu time...
But how do I "pass a functor" which should be done in the same way regardless of sort/partial_sort..

Comment: See MadKeithV's answer for an example implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass along a comparator as the fourth argument to [`std::partial_sort`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/partial_sort.html) or [`std::sort`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/sort.html), so just write a function object with a call operator taking two vector arguments that compare your vectors the way you want to.